# using asp.net "membership" for mysql database throws Keyword not supported. Parameter name: metadata error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, datacontext, mysql-connector

I am trying to use Membership class for my asp.net mvc3 application with Entity framework to use Mysql database. I am using EF DbContext. 
Following some threads i have changed the MySQLMembershipProvider of machine.config to

```
<add name="MySQLMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="book_shelfEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true" applicationName="/" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Clear" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1" passwordAttemptWindow="10" passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" autogenerateschema="true"/>
```

where book_shelfEntities is the name of my connection string.

My connectionStrings in web.config is as

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" 
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated  Security=SSPI;        AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="book_shelfEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.libs.csdl|res://*/Models.libs.ssdl|res://*/Models.libs.msl;provider=MySql.Data.MySqlClient;provider connection string='server=localhost;User Id=root;password=root;Persist Security Info=True;database=book_shelf'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

and membership in web.config is as

```
<membership defaultProvider="MySqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
    <clear />
        <add name="MySqlMembershipProvider" type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" connectionStringName="book_shelfEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="100" minRequiredPasswordLength="2" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

i have a table named users with username and password fields.
When i try to use Membership.ValidateUser VS2010 throws an error

Keyword not supported.
Parameter name: metadata  in my web.config file corresponding to my membership provider name

Please help me to resolve the issue as i am very new to asp.net
(i can use Mysql tables in other sections for adding , editing etc)